# Java: How to parse double from certain string position and get the position of the char after it?

Tags: java, parsing, precision, decimalformat

I want something similar to `std::stod` from C++.
The closest thing I've found is a `DecimalFormat` class, but the big issue with it is that it acts differently from `Double.parseDouble()`. For example, it parses `3.14E+2` as `3.14` instead of `314`. While `Double.parseDouble()` gives the same answer for both cases and this is behavior I want. And replacing all `E+` with just `E` is not a desirable option (it could potentially break other things).

So basically I want `Double.parseDouble()` with ability to set starting position and get back ending position. Is there some way to achieve this in Java without re-implementing the whole double parsing routine?

Comment: how about just taking a substring of your choice and calling Double.parseDouble() on that?

Comment: @eis how would you know how much should you take? Remember: I want to get the index past the end of the double.

Comment: You need to specify things precisely. Let's take 3.14E+2. With your (absence of) specification, it could be parsed as 3, and the index past the double would be 1. Or be parsed as 3.14, and the index past the double would be 4. Or be parsed as 314 and the index past the double would be 7. So you need to define what you consider part of the double value and what you don't, and how the parser should behave.

Comment: @DanM. one option is to do what [the javadocs suggest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)), scan the string first with a regular expression to get indexes. Another option is to use [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) that has nextDouble() method, though I'm not sure if it covers your use case fully.

Comment: @JBNizet I specified it as I want to get the same result that `Double.parseDouble()` would give (but with ability to specify/retrieve `ParsePosition`).

Comment: @eis yeah, Scanner want do, since I want to be able to work with the string exactly past the parsed double. I was considering the regexp implementation, though it still feels very cumbersome, since I'd have to take sub-string/embed starting position in it, get the first match and compute it's length, and regexp itself is like half/quarter of the double parsing. I'd really want to keep it to lib methods if at all possible. But I'd probably use it if it turns out the Java lib is not flexible enough for my simple use case.

Comment: Double.parseDouble() will accept 3, 3.14, and 3.14E+2, and will reject 3.14E+2aa, for example. So *you* need to decide what to parse as double. Using a regexp, or using the index of the first character that can't possibly pas part of a double, or by trying to parse as many chars as possible until it fails, or... you decide.

Comment: @JBNizet
`Double.parseDouble()` rejects `3.14E+2aa` only because it considers the whole string to be a of a double. What I want (and how approximately `std::stod` acts), is to have something like `ParsePos p = new ParsePos(0); Double.parseDouble("3.14E+2aa", p); // Now p.index is 7, since aa is not part of the parsed double`. Basically start parsing the string from a given position, parse as much as possible , return the result and set the index to the next non-parsed char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanner class is quite close to what you ask:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class ScanFloat {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String str = "foo 3.14E+2 xx";
        int startPos = 4;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(str.substring(4));
        s.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(s.nextDouble());
        System.out.println("endingPos: " + (startPos + getPos(s)));

    }
    static int getPos(Scanner s) throws Exception {
      Field f = Scanner.class.getDeclaredField("position");
      f.setAccessible(true);
      return (int) f.get(s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
314.0
endingPos: 11
```

However, input `"foo 3.14E+2xx"` would throw an exception. Depending on your use case it might or might not be ok.

Using regular expressions gets you around that and it's not that hard either, given you just use the [patterns from the documentation I linked](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class RegexFloat {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String testString = "foo 3.14E+2xx";
        AtomicInteger parsePos = new AtomicInteger(0);
        Double d = parseDouble(testString, parsePos);
        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(parsePos);
    }

    static Double parseDouble(String str, AtomicInteger parsePos) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(fpRegex);
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str.substring(parsePos.get()));

        if (m.find()) {
            parsePos.set(m.end(1));
            return Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
        }
        return null;
    }

    // or Pattern.compile(String.format(".{%d}%s", parsePos.get(), fpRegex));
    // if you want to avoid substring above for some reason and
    // want to add offset into the pattern


    static final String Digits     = "(\\p{Digit}+)";
    static final String HexDigits  = "(\\p{XDigit}+)";
    // an exponent is 'e' or 'E' followed by an optionally
    // signed decimal integer.
    static final String Exp        = "[eE][+-]?"+Digits;
    static final String fpRegex    =
      ("[\\x00-\\x20]*"+  // Optional leading "whitespace"
       "[+-]?(" + // Optional sign character
       "NaN|" +           // "NaN" string
       "Infinity|" +      // "Infinity" string

       // A decimal floating-point string representing a finite positive
       // number without a leading sign has at most five basic pieces:
       // Digits . Digits ExponentPart FloatTypeSuffix
       //
       // Since this method allows integer-only strings as input
       // in addition to strings of floating-point literals, the
       // two sub-patterns below are simplifications of the grammar
       // productions from section 3.10.2 of
       // The Java™ Language Specification.

       // Digits ._opt Digits_opt ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
       "((("+Digits+"(\\.)?("+Digits+"?)("+Exp+")?)|"+

       // . Digits ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
       "(\\.("+Digits+")("+Exp+")?)|"+

       // Hexadecimal strings
       "((" +
        // 0[xX] HexDigits ._opt BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
        "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "(\\.)?)|" +

        // 0[xX] HexDigits_opt . HexDigits BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
        "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "?(\\.)" + HexDigits + ")" +

        ")[pP][+-]?" + Digits + "))" +
       "[fFdD]?))" +
       "[\\x00-\\x20]*");// Optional trailing "whitespace"    
}
```

Output:

```
314.0
11
```

Comment: Thanks, but yeah. Looks like not what I want exactly. Because 1) it still involves the copying of the string which I ideally want to avoid (since it's completely not necessary for the given task), 2) cases like `"foo 3.14E+2xx"` are exactly what I parse might look like. I.e. different tokens are not necessarily space separated. 3) is it accessing private/protected field? Feels to hacky =)

Comment: yeah, it would be either using a library for it or implementing it yourself then (using regexp or implementing a tokenizer). though I didn't get what you mean by copying a string.

Comment: @DanM. so added now the regular expression alternative. Wouldn't that satisfy the requirements?

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it. By copying the string I meant that there is no need to create `substring`, since the algo doesn't modify the string, but it looks like it's not possible due to Java std lib limitations.

Comment: I added also a comment about pushing the startup position to regular expression as well, that way you can avoid the substring if you want to. though regular expressions by themselves do a lot behind the scenes so personally i'd just use the substring.